# Backup solo directorios

Tags: linux

Actualmente en nuestra empresa tenemos un servidor `linux` en el cual se crean diariamente diferentes carpetas y necesitamos que guarde solo la estructura de las carpetas sin la información.

Comment: Ajá. Ahora que sabemos lo que necesitáis, ¿puedes decirnos qué has probado? Suponiendo que esta sea una pregunta de programación, claro (las preguntas de manejo de sistema operativo son off-topic)

Comment: Hola, despues de buscar un poco mas encontre una solucion muy buena que podrán encontrar aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073969/copy-folder-structure-sans-files-from-one-location-to-another

Comment: En ese vínculo se menciona esta [otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40586240/2002514) usando rsync, ya que al hacer un backup es muy probable que quieras preservar los permisos y los atributos de los directorios lo que no sucede con el método que citas.

Answer (score 3):

**Con un programa (opción cómoda)**

Instalas `tree` (`apt-get install tree` en caso de que sea un sistema que maneja dpkg).

Ejecutas `tree -da /home/hamza/directorio-master > tuarchivo.txt`, cambiando `/home/hamza/directorio-master` por tu directorio (el que quieres analizar y ver que sub-directorios tiene), también cambias `tuarchivo.txt` por el archivo en el que quieras guardar el resultado.

Opciones:

`-d` = solo lista los directorios

`-a` = lista los directorios (u archivos) ocultos

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Sin un programa (opción eficiente)**

Ejecutas `find /home/hamza/directorio-master type -d > tuarchivo.txt`, cambiando `/home/hamza/directorio-master` por tu directorio (el que quieres analizar y ver que sub-directorios tiene), también cambias `tuarchivo.txt` por el archivo en el que quieras guardar el resultado.

Opciones:

`-d` = solo busca los directorios

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]